# Asking for the amount of questions the user got right out of 100 questions

Tags: python

I am relativly new to Python. My code doesnt work and so far I am getting these errors messages. Below these error messages is my code.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in total `


 
import math 

def total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS):
    if correct_answers > NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS:
        raise ValueError("Your total cannot be more than the number of questions.")
    return math.ceil(correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 100
   
try:
    correct_answers = int(input("How many answers did you get right in the test? "))
except ValueError as err:
    print("Oh no, thats not a valid value!")
else:
    final_result = total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
if final_result <= 50:
    print("I think you need to revise more.")
elif final_result <= 70 and final_result > 50:
    print("You did quite well! Why dont you try revise more to get a higher score!")
else:
    print("You did superb! Congrats!!!!")
```

Comment: You didn't post the actual error message, it's cut off.

Comment: Also, if the user enters an invalid value, you have no loop in place to retry the input until a correct one is given. Other than that when I run the code I get no errors so it's important that you put the actual error here.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that my code is not working. It is working in terms of without any errors but but it's not doing what its supposed to. For example if I type 60 as my 90 as my score, I still get the output of "You need to revise more"

Comment: Oh I understand the issue now, I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in `total()`:

```
def total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS):
    if correct_answers > NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS:
        raise ValueError("Your total cannot be more than the number of questions.")
    return math.ceil(correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
```

You're returning the ceiling of the number of correct answers divided by the number of questions. Meaning that if you got 50% of the answers correct, the result of the division is 0.5, and then you're using the ceiling to raise it to 1. Meaning that the function basically only ever returns 1.

In order for your code to work no matter what value `NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS` has, you have a few options. One is to multiply the result of `total()` by 100 before applying `ceil` to it. Another is to just return the non-ceiling value and change the range of your `if` statements.

Here's the first way:

```
def total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS):
    if correct_answers > NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS:
        raise ValueError("Your total cannot be more than the number of questions.")
    return math.ceil(100 * correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
```

And the second way:

```
import math 

def total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS):
    if correct_answers > NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS:
        raise ValueError("Your total cannot be more than the number of questions.")
    return correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS
NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 100
   
try:
    correct_answers = int(input("How many answers did you get right in the test? "))
except ValueError as err:
    print("Oh no, thats not a valid value!")
else:
    final_result = total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
if final_result <= 0.5:
    print("I think you need to revise more.")
elif final_result <= 0.7 and final_result > 0.5:
    print("You did quite well! Why dont you try revise more to get a higher score!")
else:
    print("You did superb! Congrats!!!!")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! A lot clearer now!

Answer (score 1):

The Error you are facing is because even though the user did not insert a number, your code still performs the calculations.  A workaround would be as follows and which will keep the user trying to insert input in case the input was not integer:

```
while True: 
    try:
        correct_answers = int(input("How many answers did you get right in the test? "))
        final_result = total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
        if final_result <= 50:
            print("I think you need to revise more.")
        elif final_result <= 70 and final_result > 50 :
            print("You did quite well! Why dont you try revise more to get a higher score!")
        else:
            print("You did superb! Congrats!!!!") 
    except ValueError as err:
        print("Oh no, thats not a valid value!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's a small math error you've got:

```
return math.ceil(correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
```

should be:

```
return math.ceil( (correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS) * 100 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't need to do math.ceil. You can simply do this as follows

```
NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 100
def total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS):
    if correct_answers > NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS:
        raise ValueError("Your total cannot be more than the number of questions.")
    return correct_answers / NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS

   
try:
    correct_answers = int(input("How many answers did you get right in the test? "))
except ValueError as err:
    print("Oh no, thats not a valid value!")
else:
    final_result = total(correct_answers, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS)
if final_result <= 0.5:
    print("I think you need to revise more.")
elif final_result <= 0.7 and final_result > 0.5:
    print("You did quite well! Why dont you try revise more to get a higher score!")
else:
    print("You did superb! Congrats!!!!")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!